# Background image not stretching fully

Tags: css, background, background-image

I just launched a website the other day and thought it was free of weird CSS mistakes, but apparently it's not. What I am trying to do here is stretching an image to fit the page in height and width.

**The problem:**
I have the following markup:

```
<img src="images/night_sky7.jpg" class="stretch" />
```

and the following CSS applied to it:

```
img.stretch { 
left: 0px;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
z-index: 0;
}
```

This is working fine on my 17.1' laptop with 1440x900 resolution, but I noticed it doesn't work properly on other screen resolutions. What happens is that the background does not stretch to the bottom, but to just below the bottom or even to the middle of the page.

Now, I've tried changing a lot of CSS, but I can't get it to fully stretch.

Any help is appreciated.

The url you could test on if you'd want is: http://bit.ly/eOEzXJ.

**If necessary, I can do any of these things:**

- Change image in Photoshop to any dimension
- Add any JS or CSS, but the height: 100%; solution does not work, at least, not as I can see

Comment: You might want to reword this. It seemed like you were trying to make an element's background stretch, which can't be done with CSS.

Comment: you shouldn't stretch a image you should always use background repeat if you want to repeat ,

Comment: @gov, thanks for your comment! However, if you take a look at the link you can see I'm not trying to repeat an image, but to stretch an image to fit the page.. the image should be large enough to do that

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this:

```
body {
   height: 100%;
}

img.stretch {
   // your stuff
   height: 100%
}
```

I noticed you also have a wrapper CSS class. You'd also need to add this:

```
#wrapper {
   height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: By way of explanation, the height of your image is being scaled to maintain the original aspect ratio. This often will not be tall enough for long documents. You might consider having the image fade into a flat colour towards the bottom.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :-) This does not seem to solve the problem, unfortunately..

Answer (score 3):

Chuck's on the right track here, but you might need to add

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

as well.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to just set the height and width of the img tag in html to 100%

```
<img src="images/night_sky7.jpg" class="stretch" width="100%" height="100%"/>
```