# Have background-image "stretch to fit" the background of my page

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I have an image I would like to use as a background image but I need the height of it to stretch to fit 100% from header to footer, and then I can drop a background-color:black; behind it to make it perfect.

Is there any way to do this? Currently I am trying to use this CSS:

```css
#wrapper .bg{
    background: url(../images/sky.png) no-repeat; 
    position:absolute; 
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%; 
    height:100%;
    display:block;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

This ends up leaving some space between the image and the footer, the same amount I am guessing as if the image wasn't there.

Comment: Side note: Typically you don't want your background stretched as this degrades the quality of the displayed image (different resolution)

Comment: Very similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379084/background-image-not-stretching-fully

Comment: Thats creepily ironic, and the image I'm using is at such a high reolution that the quality isn't being degraded but thank you for that heads up for future endeavours

Comment: Ironic? I don't see the irony.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, what you need to do is add an image tag inside the body and set the height to 100%. Apply any z-index tweaks with CSS so it remains behind your content.

Answer (score 11):

If you aren't supporting older browsers you can use css3 to achieve this.

```
body {
  background-image: url(myimage.png);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: This has worked for myself in chrome32, ff26, and ie10. Thanks!